# HasMany relation inside a Join Mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, join, nhibernate-mapping

So, I'm having a problem mapping in fluent nhibernate. I want to use a join mapping to flatten an intermediate table: Here's my structure:

```
[Vehicle]
VehicleId
...

[DTVehicleValueRange]
VehicleId
DTVehicleValueRangeId
AverageValue
...

[DTValueRange]
DTVehicleValueRangeId
RangeMin
RangeMax
RangeValue
```

Note that DTValueRange does not have a VehicleID. I want to flatten DTVehicleValueRange into my Vehicle class. Tgis works fine for AverageValue, since it's just a plain value, but I can't seem to get a ValueRange collection to map correctly.

```
    public VehicleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "VehicleId");
        Join("DTVehicleValueRange", x =>
        {
            x.Optional();
            x.KeyColumn("VehicleId");
            x.Map(y => y.AverageValue).ReadOnly();
            x.HasMany(y => y.ValueRanges).KeyColumn("DTVehicleValueRangeId"); // This Guy
        });
    }
```

The HasMany mapping doesn't seem to do anything if it's inside the Join. If it's outside the Join and I specify the table, it maps, but nhibernate tries to use the VehicleID, not the DTVehicleValueRangeId.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, as are others (http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/4ed6822592f64f9d).  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. The best I got was "That's not how you are supposed to use NHibernate". My understanding is that it will map a table to multiple objects, but not map an object to multiple tables. (Or at least the support for that isn't there.) I have switched projects since then, and am not currently using NHibernate, so my information may be out of date.

Comment: This problem also has me totally stumped. Really causing me headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the average value column in the `DTVehicleValueRange` table? Isn't this a calculated value (i.e. no need to persist it)?

It looks like you have a many-to-many relationship between `Vehicle` and `DTValueRange`, which of course would not be mapped with a join, rather with a `HasManyToMany` call.

Comment: The DTVehicleValueRange is extracted from another data source; We don't have access to the source values at run time, so we do persist the average. Since the base values are updated quarterly, there's no real time requirement. The Vehicle to DTValueRange is mapped as a many-to-many, but in reality, there's always a one-to-one relationship. (I know that's not recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue today using a Map to create a view.  The SQL generated showed it  trying to do the HasMany<> inside the join based on the Id of the ParentThing and not WorkThing (same problem you were having)

After much mapping of head-to-desk it turns out adding the propertyref onto the hasmany solved it.

```
public class ThingMap : ClassMap<WorkThingView> { 
     public ThingMap() {
                ReadOnly();
                Table("ParentThing");
                Id(x => x.ParentThingId);
                Map(x => x.ParentName);
                Join("WorkThing", join => {
                    join.KeyColumn("ParentThingId");
                    join.Map(m => m.FooCode);
                    join.Map(m => m.BarCode);
                    join.Map(x => x.WorkThingId);
                    join.HasMany(x => x.WorkThingCodes)
                        .Table("WorkThingCode").KeyColumn("WorkThingId").PropertyRef("WorkThingId")
                        .Element("WorkThingCode");
                });
            }
}
```